# How do I get the type definition for the fetch function in my Typescript React Native project?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have imported the react and react-native modules and have the type definitions for them installed (via [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings)).

The fetch function is not recognised. How can I get it working?

```
src/reducers/calendar/actions.ts(16,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'fetch'.
```

Comment: It appears newer versions of TypeScript have the fetch definitions built in, but I have found libraries such as Axios have type definitions including generics built in, so are nicer to use

Answer (score 1):

## Updated 2017-09-12

This solution does not work because current Typescript deprecated `typings.json`.

## Updated 2016-10-28

I forgot that I patched the react-native typings before. I added this line in `typings/globals/react-native/index.d.ts`.

```
5643: export type fetch = (url: string, options?: Object) => Promise<any>
5644: export const fetch: fetch;    // patch `fetch` not found problem
```

## Original

I added the following line to the start of the file (`action.ts` in your case) to solve this problem.

```
import {fetch} from "react-native";
```

My `typings.json`:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "fbemitter": "registry:dt/fbemitter#2.0.0+20160618175531",
    "flux": "registry:dt/flux#0.0.0+20160618175531",
    "immutable": "registry:dt/immutable#3.8.1+20160608070634",
    "react": "registry:dt/react#0.14.0+20160927082313",
    "react-dom": "registry:dt/react-dom#0.14.0+20160412154040",
    "react-native": "registry:dt/react-native#0.29.0+20160928135220",
    "react-native-button": "file:typings/custom/react-native-button/index.d.ts",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "file:typings/custom/react-native-fbsdk/index.d.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-router-flux": "npm:react-native-router-flux",
    "rxjs": "npm:rxjs"
  }
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "SomeApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "flux": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-native": "0.34.1",
    "react-native-button": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-linkedin-login": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^0.1.22",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.35.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "typings": "1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get `src/reducers/calendar/actions.ts(18,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'fetch'.` I am using this type definition file (from typings.json): `    "react-native": "registry:dt/react-native#0.29.0+20160830141535"`

Comment: I am using this type definition: "react-native": "registry:dt/react-native#0.29.0+20160928135220". It seems mine is newer. Let me check what's changed

Comment: @cubabit Hi I am the maintainer of react-native.d.ts. `fetch` is exported as a type using `export type fetch = (url: string, options?: Object) => Promise<any>`. This definition can certainly be improved - as indicated in the TODO above - but is there. Can you check your d.ts file ?

Comment: @cubabit Sorry that I forgot that I patched the typing locally before. Please refer to this [issue].(https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/12198). I am submitting an pull request.